# Inno Setup Installer Not Working in Windows 7

Tags: windows, deployment, inno-setup

i'm trying to create an installer for my .exe game application i've created in java that I need to deliver as a college assignment, however i'm just using the basic Inno Setup Script Wizard to pack it up and get the installer, but seems like i'm having issues when i'm trying to open the created installer in Windows 7, it works fine in windows 10 and windows 8/8.1, but the installer doesn't works in windows 7, it doesn't open or anything, but it shows that the process is active in the task manager of windows 7.

Here's the code that the Wizard Script tool generated

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{21BF7A5F-3140-4AE4-B564-593CCF9FC983}
AppName=Crossy Road 2D
AppVersion=1.0
;AppVerName=Crossy Road 2D 1.0
AppPublisher=Cryo
DefaultDirName={pf}\Crossy Road 2D
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\Cryo Codex\Desktop\Installer
OutputBaseFilename=Crossy Raod 2D Installer
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Cryo Codex\Downloads\c1.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Cryo Codex\Desktop\Executable\Crossy Road 2D.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\Crossy Road 2D"; Filename: "{app}\Crossy Road 2D.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Crossy Road 2D"; Filename: "{app}\Crossy Road 2D.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\Crossy Road 2D.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Crossy Road 2D}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: Is there any information in the Windows Event Log? Have you tried running with an option to create a log file and then examined the log for any info?

Comment: No related information in the event log and it doesn't create the log file using the cmd

Comment: Seems like the installation just hangs in task manager with 58 kb of memory usage in windows 7, i don't get why this is happening while in the other mentioned operating systems is working

Comment: Does it hang even before you get the "elevation prompt"? How long did you try to wait?

Comment: Maybe it is waiting for you to do the elevation but not in the foreground (check your taskbar)? To see what is going on, please use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to get the call stacks of the threads running in the process (double-click process, go to threads tab, select thread and click "Stack", etc) and post them here. To get more details, you could also create a dump by right-clicking the process in task manager and choosing "dump". The dump can then be analyzed to see what the process was doing at that moment.

Comment: Change the name of your OutputBaseFilename. Recompile and try again,

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Avast protection if you have a problem running the installer.